# Symfony : Attribute "Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Table" must not be repeated

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, attributes

Sorry for my English (gg translation).
I just passed all my entities with attributes instead of annotations.
Everything was working before and now I have this error.
I can't get it up. Do you have an idea ?
Thanks

composer.json :

```
Symfony 6.1.*
"php": ">=8.0.2",
"doctrine/annotations": "^1.13",
"doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^2.6",
"doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^3.2",
"doctrine/orm": "^2.12",
```

doctrine.yaml

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'

        # IMPORTANT: You MUST configure your server version,
        # either here or in the DATABASE_URL env var (see .env file)
        #server_version: '13'
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
        auto_mapping: true
        mappings:
            App:
                is_bundle: false
                #type: annotation
                type: attribute
                dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                prefix: 'App\Entity'
                alias: App
        dql:
           numeric_functions:
              acos: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Acos
              cos: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Cos
              radians: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Radians
              sin: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Sin
```

error message : "Attribute "Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Table" must not be repeated"

[image: Attribute "Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Table" must not be repeated]

Answer (score 2):

I made the modification of the annotations in attributes with rector.

In one of my entities, he transformed me this code:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=CodePostalRepository::class)
 * @Table(name="code_postal_villes", 
 *          uniqueConstraints={@UniqueConstraint(name="ville_code_postal", columns={"code_postal_id", "villes_id"})}
 *      )
 * @Table(name="code_postal",
 *           indexes={@Index(name="cp_idx",columns={"cp"})},
 *           uniqueConstraints={@UniqueConstraint(name="cp", columns={"cp"})}
 *      )
 */
```

in :

```
#[Table(name: 'code_postal_villes')]
#[UniqueConstraint(name: 'ville_code_postal', columns: ['code_postal_id', 'villes_id'])]
#[Table(name: 'code_postal')]
#[Index(name: 'cp_idx', columns: ['cp'])]
#[UniqueConstraint(name: 'cp', columns: ['cp'])]
#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: CodePostalRepository::class)]
```

This is what poses the problem.
There cannot be twice the table attribute

It remains to be seen how I solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Same for me: I made the modifications with rector
It transformed this code:

```
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="DropzoneRepository::class")
* @ORM\Table(name="dropzone")
* @ORM\Entity
```

into:

```
#[ORM\Table(name: 'dropzone')]
#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: DropzoneRepository::class)]
#[ORM\Entity]
```

The last line must be **removed** or you get two ORM\Entity annotations:

```
//#[ORM\Entity]
```